# Update main page / minimize downtime

Tags: uploading

I plan on updating my main page frequently but I'm concerned about downtime.  There seems to be a significant lag between when I FTP a file to the server and when I can get it to load in a web browser.  I see a lot of `No data received ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` when I point my browser at the uploaded file.

My best idea to combat this is to create a symbolic link pointing to the current version and list that symbolic link first in the `.htaccess DirectoryIndex`, upload the new version with a different filename, wait until I get the new file to load in a browser, and finally update the symbolic link to point to the new version of the page.

I'm using bluehost currently.

Is there a better way?  Will I still get that error if I try to do it this way?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably upload the file under a different filename (ie index.new), then (assuming you get a shell or the ftp supports it) rename the old file to index.x (could version them or just make it .old) and rename the new file to whatever your page is.
The problem you have seems to be that the upload will overwrite the old page (ftp deletes it, then gets the whole new page, and finally has to close the file before the webserver can read it) which might take a while. Renames should be instant.

Comment: I always advise renaming old files before uploading new ones or the other way around like you said- upload the file under a different name and then rename the original and the new into place. This is far superior to overwriting unless you have CYA another way. It is about covering your bases just in case. You never know when your shell session fails halfway through the process.